# easy_install downloading directory

Tags: python, easy-install

I'm trying to install a python script packaged in egg format using easy_install.  The problem is that easy_install downloads dependencies to /tmp.  However, my tmp dir only has 4mb of free space (I am working with a NAS drive, set up this way).

Is there a way of specifying the download directory?  --help doesn't seem to throw up anything useful.

**Edit:**

Some more details:

I'm running python 2.5.6 and setuputils 0.6c11-2 installed from optware. The NAS is ARM based (specifically the DNS-320 with fun_plug installed).  Please let me know if you'd like any more specific info.

When I use the -b option, the file is still downloaded to /tmp.  It is in fact the extraction process which which uses the remaining space in tmp:

> ```
> easy_install-2.5 -b /mnt/HD/HD_a2/ffp/home/root SQLAlchemy==0.7.2
> Searching for SQLAlchemy==0.7.2
> Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/SQLAlchemy/
> Reading http://www.sqlalchemy.org
> Best match: SQLAlchemy 0.7.2
> Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/SQLAlchemy/SQLAlchemy-0.7.2.tar.gz#md5=b84a26ae2e5de6f518d7069b29bf8f72
> Processing SQLAlchemy-0.7.2.tar.gz
> error: No space left on device
> ```

I know the file is downloaded into /tmp by running ls -l /tmp/ while the download is happening:

> ```
> ls -l /tmp/easy_install*
> total 891 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 901120 Oct  1 20:35 SQLAlchemy-0.7.2.tar.gz
> ```

df -h output:

> ```
> Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
> rootfs                9.7M  4.8M  4.5M  52% /
> /dev/root             9.7M  4.8M  4.5M  52% /
> /dev/loop0             23M   23M     0 100% /usr/local/modules
> /dev/mtdblock5        5.0M  464K  4.6M  10% /usr/local/config
> /dev/sda4             485M   16M  469M   4% /mnt/HD_a4
> /dev/sdb4             485M   11M  474M   3% /mnt/HD_b4
> /dev/sda2             1.8T  213G  1.6T  12% /mnt/HD/HD_a2
> /dev/sdb2             1.8T   69G  1.8T   4% /mnt/HD/HD_b2
> /dev/sda2             1.8T  213G  1.6T  12% /opt
> ```

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well here's the solution if anyone's interested.

Edit line 412 of /opt/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py from:

```
tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix="easy_install-")
```

to:

```
tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix="easy_install-",dir="/opt/tmp")
```

This works, as /opt is mounted to the HDD and has plenty of free space.

I'm no python expert (never programmed with it), but it seems like the -b option has no bearing on where the file is downloaded to.

Answer (score 16):

Set TMPDIR environment variable such as following:

```
export TMPDIR="/opt/tmp"
```

I think this is a better way than rewriting the easy_install.py. You need to ensure the path exists.

Answer (score 4):

```
easy_install -b wherever
```

or

```
easy_install --build-directory wherever
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work - it still downloads to /tmp. A bug perhaps?

Comment: Can you give some more information about your setup?  I just tried `easy_install -b some_test_directory bottle` on my mbp (osx lion) and it worked fine

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have provided some more info in the original question.

Comment: @Jack where are the python modules going?  It looks like /use/local/modules has no free space ...

Comment: They are being installed to /opt/local/lib/python2.5.  The error is definitely due to packages being downloaded to /tmp instead of the dir specified by -b.

Answer (score 0):

hmmmmm, you may soft symlink that /tmp/easyinstall to another location before starting the process?
I am not a pro in the tool so it's an idea to get going, not a solution

Comment: Thanks, it's an idea, but easy_install actually appends a random string to the dir, e.g. /tmp/easy_install-XXXX.  So this probably isn't possible.